# How to apply a complex function across crossed levels of factors in data.frame (in R)?

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I want to apply a function accross the crossed levels of factors in a `data.frame` similar to what `aggregate` would do, but for more complex functions than `aggregate` can handle.

For example.

```
fact1=c(rep('A',6),rep('B',6))
fact2=c(rep(c(rep('C',3),rep('D',3)),2))
crit1=rnorm(12)
crit2=crit1+rnorm(12)
dat=data.frame(fact1,fact2,crit1,crit2)

target.fit = function(dat){
  mod=lm(dat$crit2~dat$crit1)
  return(mod$coefficients[2])
}
```

This code generates a `data.frame` `dat`. The goal is to apply `target.fit` to each of the crossed levels of `fact1` and `fact2` (here an `lm`).

It is simple to do this for functions that require only one input vector such as the mean using `aggregate`.

```
> aggregate(dat,list(fact1=fact1,fact2=fact2),mean)
  fact1 fact2 fact1 fact2      crit1      crit2
1     A     C    NA    NA -0.5875951 -0.6048572
2     B     C    NA    NA  0.3712372  0.9135742
3     A     D    NA    NA -1.0163750 -2.4971846
4     B     D    NA    NA  0.3937682  0.6227697
```

However, `aggregate` does not work for multi-variate inputs.

```
> aggregate(dat,list(fact1=fact1,fact2=fact2),target.fit)
 Error in dat$crit2 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How can I solve this programing problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `formula` method to avoid getting `NA` column

```
 aggregate(.~fact1+fact2, dat, FUN=mean)
```

For the custom function

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(dat)[,target.fit(.SD) ,.(fact1, fact2)]
 #   fact1 fact2       V1
 #1:     A     C 1.060835
 #2:     A     D 1.259871
 #3:     B     C 1.451595
 #4:     B     D 1.766432
```

which is the same as

```
 setDT(dat)[, coef(lm(crit2~crit1))[2] ,.(fact1, fact2)]
 #   fact1 fact2       V1
 #1:     A     C 1.060835
 #2:     A     D 1.259871
 #3:     B     C 1.451595
 #4:     B     D 1.766432
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 dat %>% 
     group_by(fact1, fact2) %>% 
     do(data.frame(V1=target.fit(.)))
 #  fact1 fact2       V1
 #1     A     C 1.060835
 #2     A     D 1.259871
 #3     B     C 1.451595
 #4     B     D 1.766432
```

A `base R` option is

```
 sapply(split(dat, as.list(dat[paste0('fact',1:2)]), drop=FALSE), target.fit)
 #A.C.dat$crit1 B.C.dat$crit1 A.D.dat$crit1 B.D.dat$crit1 
 #   1.060835      1.451595      1.259871      1.766432
```

Or

```
  by(dat, list(dat$fact1, dat$fact2), FUN=target.fit)
```

To get factor levels in a data.frame,

```
  do.call(rbind,by(dat, list(dat$fact1, dat$fact2), 
           FUN=function(x) cbind(x[1,1:2], V1=target.fit(x))))
```

NOTE: Used `set.seed(24)` as seed for creating the `dat`

Comment: Okay this works. Is there a way to do this without converting to `data.table`?

Comment: @tomka I also posted the `dplyr` version, which doesn't need conversion to `data.table`

Answer (score 2):

In the days before data.table and dplyr, the standard method was `lapply(split(data,fators),func)`

```
> lapply( split( dat, list(fact1, fact2) ), target.fit)
$A.C
dat$crit1 
 1.328941 

$B.C
dat$crit1 
0.3281161 

$A.D
dat$crit1 
 -0.10337 

$B.D
dat$crit1 
   2.8962
```

The split function on a dataframe argument returns smaller dataframes composed of subsets based on the crossed factors arguments. If you needed it to be as a vector, the sapply function could be substituted for the lapply:

```
> sapply( split( dat, list(fact1, fact2) ), target.fit)
A.C.dat$crit1 B.C.dat$crit1 A.D.dat$crit1 B.D.dat$crit1 
    1.3289409     0.3281161    -0.1033700     2.8962000
```

I probably would have written the function to pass the dat argument tot the data argument of `lm`:

```
target.fit = function(dat){
  mod=lm(crit2~$crit1, data=dat)
  return(mod$coefficients[2])
}
```